# How to optimize a redshift query that join table with itself?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, query-optimization

Let say I have a transaction table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS txn_raw (
transaction_id VARCHAR(60),
sport_label VARCHAR(300),
family_label VARCHAR(150),
item_label VARCHAR(150)
)
DISTKEY (the_transaction_id)
SORTKEY (the_transaction_id, sport_label, family_label, item_label)
;
COMMIT;
```

And I want to optimize following query for calculation correlation between items.

```
SELECT 
a.sport_label as sport_label_a, 
a.family_label as family_label_a, 
a.dsm_label as dsm_label_a, 
b.sport_label as sport_label_b, 
b.family_label as family_label_b, 
b.dsm_label as dsm_label_b, 
count(distinct a.the_transaction_id) as txn_ab
FROM txn_raw a
JOIN txn_raw b 
on a.the_transaction_id=b.the_transaction_id
and a.sport_label != b.sport_label
and a.family_label != b.family_label
and a.item_label != b.item_label
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I am thinking to create a temp table storing data after joining txn_raw with itself.
Then query the temp table and do group by.

Is there any better way to optimize this kind of query?

Comment: You already appear to have an index covering all 4 columns.  Is that right?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You should look at and provide the explain plan and the actual execution timing for the query.  Since you asked an optimization question I expect the query is taking too long.  The first questions is why.  With that known it is then on to what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest extracting the *distinct* values before joining rather than afterwards:

```
WITH r as (
      SELECT DISTINCT the_transaction_id, sport_label, family_label, item_label
      FROM txn_raw
     )
SELECT a.sport_label as sport_label_a, 
       a.family_label as family_label_a, 
       a.dsm_label as dsm_label_a, 
       b.sport_label as sport_label_b, 
       b.family_label as family_label_b, 
       b.dsm_label as dsm_label_b, 
       COUNT(*) as txn_ab
FROM r a JOIN 
     r b 
     ON a.the_transaction_id = b.the_transaction_id AND
        a.sport_label <> b.sport_label AND
        a.family_label <> b.family_label AND
        a.item_label <> b.item_label
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6;
```

I also expect the actual `JOIN` condition you want is:

```
FROM r a JOIN 
     r b 
     ON a.the_transaction_id = b.the_transaction_id AND
        NOT (a.sport_label = b.sport_label AND
             a.family_label = b.family_label AND
             a.item_label = b.item_label
            )
```

That is . . . Any of the columns are different, not all of them.

Comment: Thanks! May I know the reason behind why it is better to do the distinct first?

Comment: @LouisLaw . . . Prevents a proliferation of rows, which just slows down subsequent processing.